# What is a proper situation for await Task.StartNew(() => ...)?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I was wondering whether someone could help me figure out a proper use for code like

```
var result = await Task.StartNew(() => ...);
```

or

```
var result = await Task<T>.StartNew(() => ...);
```

From what I understand, it would never make sense to have simply

```
await Task.StartNew(() => ...);
```

or

```
await Task<T>.StartNew(() => ...);
```

because if you don't need the result then you might as well fire-and-forget with

```
Task.StartNew(() => ...)
```

or

```
Task.StartNew<T>(() => ...)
```

which which is like

```
Thread A | ----- Stuff before the Task.StartNew ---- | ---- Stuff after the Task.StartNew ------------------
Thread B | ------------ ??? ------------------------ | The () => .... inside the Task.StartNew -------------
```

Can someone provide me with a real-life example of when this would be useful?

Comment: They all seem fine. What do you mean by "proper"?

Comment: There is no such thing as `Task.StartNew`. Try and see for yourself.

Comment: see this maybe it helps you[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16488818/whats-the-difference-between-using-task-and-tasktresult-in-c-sharp]

Comment: `await` is a way of signalling "there is no useful work for the current thread to do until *this* result is available". Starting a new `Task` is a way of pushing work onto (potentially) another thread so as to not tie up the current thread in performing that work. I can't think of many ways to tie those two concepts together in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 3):

None!

Unless you know exactly what and why you're doing it, you should never use `Task.Factory.StartNew` or `Task<T>.Factory.StartNew` with `async-await`.

- [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/)
- [StartNew is Dangerous](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html)
- [Task.Run Etiquette and Proper Usage](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/10/taskrun-etiquette-and-proper-usage.html)

Not awaitng on the result of a task does not mean that you don't care about the result value. It means you don't care if it completes with success or even if it completes.

Comment: So if you *do* know exactly what and why you're doing it, there *is* a use? Thus contradicting your first sentence?

Comment: Always, @AakashM! But you'll, most certainly get what you asked for.